# Game programming: remove movement lag (jumping)

Tags: javascript, physics

I'm developing an HTML5 3D fps-like engine that already looks quite nice, but as this might be one of the worst language choices to make 3D there's noticeable lag sometimes.

I programmed movements (WASD) to be independent of rendering speed, so sometimes it's quite jerky, but other times is working at an acceptable 30+ fps (depending on CPU of course).

The only thing I can't wrap my mind around is jumping: currently the jumping is done by adding a positive constant to the falling variable (gravity is always negative and then corrected by collision detection) and then subtracting a constant, this is called every time a new frame is rendered, the thing is that when fps go low I feel like I'm on the moon. I prefer jerkiness to slow-mo effect.

If I use the same method like I do for moving (calculate time between current and last frame) the deducted variable gets too big sometimes and the jumping apex changes (to half of the value compared to high fps) - this is unacceptable as jumping height must be always the same.

Here's some pseudo-code to help understanding the problem (called during one rendering routine):

```
// when clicked on spacebar:
if(spacebar)
{
    // this defines jumping apex
    jump = 0.5
}

// constant added to y (vertical position) later in the code
cy += jump;

// terminal velocity = -2
if(jump > -2)
{
    // gravity (apex multiple to get maximum height)
    jump -= 0.05;
}

if(collision_with_floor)
{
    // stop falling
    cy = 0;

    if(jump < 0)
    {
        jump = 0;
    }
}

player.position.y += cy;
```

Now with time dependent jumping (replace in the code above):

```
// terminal velocity = -2
if(jump > -2)
{
    // gravity, 0.4 is an arbitrary constant
    jump -= (now - last_frame)*0.4;
    last_frame = now;
}
```

To illustrate even better here's an image of what's going on:

[image]

Blue dots indicate frame renders.

I'm not even sure of this is the right way to program jumping routine. Basically jerkiness and constant jumping height is better than smoothness and slow-mo effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the frame updates are coming too slowly to get accurate physics, then maybe you can hack in the jump apex so that the player always hits it. The cue here might be when the y velocity changes from positive to negative. If I'm reading your pseudocode right, then it looks like:

```
old_cy = cy;
cy += jump;
if(old_cy > 0 && cy <= 0)
  player.position.y = jump_apex_height;
```

In terms of your graph, the idea is that you want to identify the blue dot that reaches the orange line, then bump it up to the dotted line.

And now that I'm thinking about it, if the player *really* has to reach the jump apex *every time*, then this might help even for high-rate updates.

Comment: This works, but isn't ideal, if I bump the orange line up to the dotted line when the player reaches the apex it becomes extremely jerky, kind of like a second small jump. On lower fps it isn't very noticeable, but on higher it's quite annoying.

Comment: Strange that the higher FPS is worse--I would have thought the distance between the ideal apex and the actual apex would have been less than for the lower FPS. Maybe instead of a sudden bump, if the player is short of the dotted line, just keep the current `cy` positive so that the player continues upwards until he reaches it.

Comment: Also, this is an interesting question, but it may get more traction at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ than at SO.